# Compare 3 SQL Server tables and once matched based on some attribute put the result on one table when not matched put the result in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the simple requirement, there are the 3 SQL Server tables like this:

- Table 1; columns

  ```
    AID  Name  DOB  Gender  PostCode
  ```
- Table 2; columns

  ```
    BID  Name  DOB  Gender  PostCode
  ```
- Table 3; columns

  ```
    CID  Name  DOB  Gender  PostCode
  ```

I wish to join (inner joins) based on Name, DOB, Gender & PostCode across all the tables, if the record matches I would like to put the result in one table and the remaining records I wish to put in another table for further comparison/processing.

The first part is simple with this query:

```
SELECT AID, BID, CID, A.Name, A.DOB, A.Gender, A.PostCode
FROM TAB_A
JOIN TAB_B B ON A.Name = B.Name 
             AND A.DOB = B.DOB 
             AND A.Gender = B.Gender 
             AND A.PostCode = B.PostCode
JOIN TAB_C C ON A.Name = C.Name 
             AND A.DOB = C.DOB 
             AND A.Gender = C.Gender 
             AND A.PostCode = C.PostCode
```

But 2nd part on the remaining records which doesn't match need to put them in a separate table.

For example if there are total 50 records in all the 3 tables (A = 20, B=20 & C=10) and the output where all the records are matching based on the above query are 5, I wish to store 95 records in the separate table.

Your help/answer will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thats seems a very strange way to join tables though, your join conditions are not unique when it comes to a person. And please show us what you tried.

Comment: Yes I am familiar on accepting the answer, let me try the below query. Also on joining it is not only I am trying to match the the columns and give them some score if it matches hence on non unique columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` to combine the tables.  Then use a window function to count the matches by the columns you care about.

Return the rows where the match is less than 3:

```
select id, Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode
from (select id, Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode,
count(*) over (partition by Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode) as cnt
      from ((select AID as id, Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode
             from a
            ) union all
            (select BID, Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode
             from b
            ) union all
            (select CID, Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode
             from c
            )
           ) abc
      ) abc
where cnt < 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your quick response. Appreciated. However in the final table I am looking for all the ID i.e. AID, BID & CID as they are coming from different source. So the final table that I need should have the column names as AID, BID, CID, Name, DOB, Gender, PostCode. Apologies for not mentioning earlier

Comment: The idea is if the attributes matches in all the 3 SQL tables on the inner join I will give them some score, for the remaining records I will match based on fewer attributes to provide them score. For example - If the attribute doesnt match in all the 3 table I will pick the remaining records and compare in only 2 tables. Hope it exaplains.

Comment: @Nitesh . . . This has the *rows* from the original table (which is how I interpreted your question), so the ids are there but in different rows.

Comment: Sure let me try the same and appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: The above has worked, I have also tried the same. Thanks for your help